# vim syntastic plugin takes the matrix multiplication @ in python as a syntastic error

Tags: python-3.x, vim, syntax

I use `vim-syntastic` to check my python code syntax. But when I use the matrix multiplication operator `@` in my code, it takes `@` as a syntactic error and open new buffer window, which is very annoying.

Here is my `vim-syntastic` plugin initial setting:

```
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 1
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_exec = 'python3'
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args = ['-m', 'flake8']
```

Now, to avoid the annoying reminder buffer,  I change them as following:

```
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 0
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 0
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 0
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_exec = 'python3'
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args = ['-m', 'flake8']
```

My question is how to make `vim-syntastic` plugin to take `@` as a correct syntax.

**update**:

My python version is 3.6.7, and my system is Ubuntu 18.04. I install `flake8` by

```py
sudo apt install python3-flake8
```

Comment: `@` has been in Python only since 3.5; is it possible your `python3` that Vim invokes, or the `flake8` for it, are outdated?

Comment: Set `g:syntastic_python_checkers` to the list of checkers you want to run.  Also see the [FAQ](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#faqpython).  Setting `g:syntastic_python_flake8_exec` to run `flake8` under Python3 is neither well supported nor recommended.